# Sophomores dream

Tags: integration, power-series

On wiki there is a proof of [Sophomore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream).

I am trying to understand what they did when changing the variable and how they got $e^{-u}$.

Comment: You're post was fine, one of us (I) could have fixed it. The more specific you can be on this site, the better. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

$x^n$ becomes $e^{\displaystyle -\frac{n}{n+1}u}$ and $dx$ becomes $$-\frac{1}{n+1}\cdot e^{\displaystyle \frac{-u}{n+1}}\, du$$Joining the two, $x^n \, dx$ ends up as $-\frac{1}{n+1}\cdot e^{-u} \, du$ (so you can see where the $e^{-u}$ comes from).

Comment: A small suggestion, you can write out the exponent as $e^{-nu/(n+1)}$, or even $\exp\left\{-\frac{n}{n+1}u\right\}.$ It looks less awkward, in my opinion.

Comment: Oh! thank you. @Fimpellizieri